# Spark History Server - Identify log file that a job writes to

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit, apache-spark-2.2

I want to use the Spark History Server API(http://127.0.0.1:18080/api/v1/applications/) to identify the log file in /tmp/spark-events/ that certain jobs write to. I can see that the job ID is the same as the log file name so was thinking if I had a unique job name I could look for that and get the associated ID. My problem here is I have a scala application which sets the application name in the code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName(s"TeraGen ($size)")
```

Each time the job is run it has the same name. Is it possible to override the application name in the command line? I tried passing `--name` but that doesn't work.

Failing that, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed a uuId as an arg by adding the following to my code and assigning it to a variable:

```
val uuId = args(2)
```

I then added it to the application name with:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName(s"TeraGen ($size) $uuId")
```